# How to loop over the redux state data after redux action has completed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a basic need about redux actions but I don't know how can i solve it.

This is my scenerio;
I have a redux action like as follows and I want to loop over the data after redux action has completed in my statefull component.

```
export const fetchServiceTypes = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchStStart());
        axios.get(GAMMA_CONSTANTS.LINK_SERVICETYPES)
            .then(res => {
                    dispatch(fetchStSuccess(res.data))
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch(fetchStFail(err))
            })
    }
}
```

In the component, I call the redux action in the componentWillMount function like as follows but I think, because redux action works asynchronously, i couldn't loop over the redux state as soon as it finished

```
componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.serviceTypes.length === 0)
            this.props.onFetchServiceTypes();

        this.props.serviceType.forEach(x => {
            // TO DO
        })
    }
```

Anybody how to solve that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is only triggered once before the component has rendered, and it doesn't care if your data is there or not. You could listen for a change in the state instead. [This article](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-react-react-16-3-component-life-cycle-23129bc7a705) explains how the new lifecycle method works.

Side note: If you are only looking to show the data you can actually loop over it directly in the html and it will be updated whenever the state is updated.